# Please tell me what is the file name of this line

Tags: phpfox

Please tell me what is the path of this line. please advice about files...

> Phpfox::getLib('module')->setController('photo.view');

Answer (score 0):

```
Phpfox::getLib('module')->setController('photo.view');

this syntax used to set another controller with in controller file.
```

photo.view

```
Photo - module name
view  - controller name

/module/photo/include/component/controller/view.class.php 

here is the file
```